# Finding Spine of Graph Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given many nodes and edges of a graph I want to find the spine of the graph.

I am attempting to try a new way of layout of a graph. I want to display the graph by finding the spine.

I could not find an algorithm by the following name.

I want to find a node A, and a node B, A!=B, such that going from A to B would result in me travelling over the most nodes. (A and B should be as far away as possible)

EDIT:
"There exists some path from node A(any node) to the node B (any node) that passes through the most internal nodes"

Bonus (not as necessary)
For more of a challenge, If there is more than one path, pick the path, which has nodes that have the most links out of those nodes.

Comment: This sounds very close to the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: But the first node should not be the last node. I also don't have to touch every node. I just want to maximize (not minimize) the numbers of nodes touched.

Comment: Still sounds NP-complete, I'm almost positive you can reduce the [Hamiltonian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem to this.

Comment: What restrictions are there on the path?  Is it "there exists some path to the node that passes through the most internal nodes," or "the shortest path to that node passes through the most internal nodes," or something else entirely?

Comment: "There exists some path from node A to the node B that passes through the most internal nodes".

Comment: @DennisMeng My graph will definitely not have such a path/ possible route. I am not trying to figure if such a path exists (for it does not), but to find a path that passes through a maximum number of nodes.

Comment: Sure, but unless you can show that your specific use case makes algorithmic optimization possible, my statement is still relevant; there's no known way to solve your problem in poly-time for the general case (and it's definitely impossible to do so if P != NP)